# How do you convert the AREA and PERIMETER fields in a QGIS attribute table from meters to sq km?

Tags: qgis

I'm looking to use the AREA and PERIMETER fields to do some field calculations in QGIS. Does anyone know how to convert these values in sq km instead of meters?

Answer (score 0):

Simple do math calculation. The formula is:

```
AREA (the field which is in meters sq) / 1000000 = resulting area in km sq
```